# Running a macro on the activeselection if more than 1 row selected but if only one selected run on activeproject

Tags: vba, ms-project

I have a macro which is designed to ensure that the rows in an MS Project plan do not have duplicate names.  At the moment this is designed to run across the whole plan and hence uses:

```
for each t in ActiveProject.tasks
code
Next t
```

It occurs to me that it could be nice to run this only on a specific set of tasks if a range of more than 1 tasks has been selected by the user, or to offer this option via a choice dialogue box.

How could I do this without needing to copy and paste the entire code set for ActiveSelection?

The full code, in case anyone finds it useful or has some better ways of doing things:

```
Sub task_names_fully_auto_de_dup()
Dim t As Task
Dim t_test As Task
Dim Dups As New Collection

For Each t In ActiveProject.Tasks
    If task_test(t) Then 'check the row is valid (not external or blank)
        For Each t_test In ActiveProject.Tasks
            If task_test(t_test) Then 'check the row is valid (not external or blank)
                'Compare t_test name to t to find dups and add to dups collection
                If t_test.Name = t.Name And t_test.ID <> t.ID Then
                    Dups.Add t.Name  'need to work out how to avoid trying to add the same name more than once
                End If
            End If
        Next t_test
    End If
Next t
 
If Dups.Count = 0 Then
    MsgBox ("No duplicates found")
    Exit Sub
Else 'offer choices for where the summary names will be added
    choice = InputBox("chose where to add the summary names." & vbCrLf & "1 = Before (prefix)" & vbCrLf & "2 = After (Suffix)", "Auto de-duplication of names 1/2", 2)
    If choice = 1 Then 'choose prefix
        Pre = InputBox("Choose which seperator you would like." & vbCrLf & "1 = Space" & vbCrLf & "2 = Dash" & vbCrLf & "3 = Colon", "Adding text to many tasks 2/2", 2)
        Select Case Pre
            Case 1
            Pre = " "
            Case 2
            Pre = " - "
            Case 3
            Pre = ": "
        End Select
    Else
        'chose suffix
        Pre = InputBox("Choose which seporator you would like." & vbCrLf & "1 = Space" & vbCrLf & "2 = Dash" & vbCrLf & "3 = Brackets", "Adding text to many tasks 2/2", 3)
        Select Case Pre
            Case 1
            Pre = " "
            Case 2
            Pre = " - "
            Case 3
            Pre = " ("
        End Select
    End If
End If
 
Dim SummaryName As String
Dim WBS_String() As String
Dim Target_WBS As String
Dim t_wbs As Task

For Each t In ActiveProject.Tasks
    If task_test(t) Then 'checks the row is valid
        Dim item As Variant
        For Each item In Dups
            If t.Name = item Then ' the item is a dup; get the next level up's name
                If InStr(1, t.WBS, ".") <> 0 Then 'if this is the top level we can't get a name
                    WBS_String = Split(t.WBS, ".")
                    ReDim Preserve WBS_String(LBound(WBS_String) To UBound(WBS_String) - 1) 'removes the last element of the WBS
                    Target_WBS = Join(WBS_String, ".") 're-join the WBS into the target WBS to find
                    For Each t_wbs In ActiveProject.Tasks ' find the target WBS and grab the name
                        If task_test(t_wbs) Then
                            If t_wbs.WBS = Target_WBS Then SummaryName = t_wbs.Name
                        End If
                    Next t_wbs
                    't.Name = t.Name & " (" & SummaryName & ")" 'add the Summary name to the task
                    If choice = 1 Then t.Name = SummaryName & Pre & t.Name
                        If choice = 2 Then
                            If Pre = " (" Then
                            t.Name = t.Name & Pre & SummaryName & ")"
                        Else
                            t.Name = t.Name & Pre & SummaryName
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next item
    End If
Next t
End Sub

Function task_test(t As Task) 'use to replace all the indents
task_test = True
If t Is Nothing Then
    task_test = False
Else
    If t.ExternalTask = True Then task_test = False
End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To allow the user to opt between all tasks and selected tasks, a collection needs to be built to hold the respective set. Then the de-duplication code runs on that set.

This code loops through the tasks only once, finding duplicates by using the fact that collections cannot contain duplicate keys. Once a duplicate is found, the first instance of that task name is de-duplicated then the current one.

```
Sub task_names_fully_auto_de_dup()


    Dim position As String
    Dim separator As String
    
    position = InputBox("chose where to add the summary names." & vbCrLf & "1 = Before (prefix)" _
                    & vbCrLf & "2 = After (suffix)", "Auto de-duplication of names 1/2", 2)
    If Len(position) = 0 Then GoTo ExitSub
    If position = "1" Then
        Dim prefix As String
        prefix = InputBox("Choose which separator you would like." & vbCrLf & "1 = Space" _
                    & vbCrLf & "2 = Dash" & vbCrLf & "3 = Colon", "Adding text to many tasks 2/2", 2)
        If Len(prefix) = 0 Then GoTo ExitSub
        separator = Choose(CSng(prefix), " ", " - ", ": ")
    Else
        Dim suffix As String
        suffix = InputBox("Choose which separator you would like." & vbCrLf & "1 = Space" _
            & vbCrLf & "2 = Dash" & vbCrLf & "3 = Brackets", "Adding text to many tasks 2/2", 3)
        If Len(suffix) = 0 Then GoTo ExitSub
        separator = Choose(CSng(suffix), " ", " - ", " (")
    End If


    Dim answer As VbMsgBoxResult
    answer = MsgBox("Run de-duplication on entire project (Yes) or only selected tasks (No)?" _
        , vbQuestion + vbYesNoCancel, "All tasks or Selected tasks?")
    Dim tsks As Variant
    Select Case answer
        Case Is = vbYes
            Set tsks = ActiveProject.Tasks
        Case Is = vbNo
            Set tsks = ActiveSelection.Tasks
        Case Else
            GoTo ExitSub
    End Select
    
    Dim t As Task
    Dim uniqueTaskNames As New Collection
    Dim tskFirstInstance As Task
    Dim uid As Variant
    
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each uid In tsks
        Set t = ActiveProject.Tasks.UniqueID(uid)
        If Not t.ExternalTask Then
            Err.Clear
            uniqueTaskNames.Add t.UniqueID, t.Name
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                Set tskFirstInstance = ActiveProject.Tasks.UniqueID(uniqueTaskNames(t.Name))
                AddPrefixSuffix position, separator, tskFirstInstance
                AddPrefixSuffix position, separator, t
            End If
        End If
    Next uid
    
ExitSub:

End Sub

Sub AddPrefixSuffix(position As String, separator As String, tsk As Task)

    If InStr(tsk.Name, tsk.OutlineParent.Name) = 0 Then
        If position = "1" Then
            tsk.Name = tsk.OutlineParent.Name & separator & tsk.Name
        ElseIf separator = " (" Then
            tsk.Name = tsk.Name & separator & tsk.OutlineParent.Name & ")"
        Else
            tsk.Name = tsk.Name & separator & tsk.OutlineParent.Name
        End If
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this.  Some aspects of the code I am unclear on, for instance what is this doing:? :  Set tskFirstInstance = ActiveProject.Tasks.UniqueID(uniqueTaskNames(t.Name))

Comment: `ActiveProject.Tasks.UniqueID` is a way to get a reference to a task by it's unique ID. `uniqueTaskNames` is a collection of task names and their UIDs; the name is the key and therefore must be unique. All tasks are added to the collection, but only the first task with a given name is successfully stored. Using the task name to look up a value in the collection returns the UID. So `uniqueTaskNames(t.Name)` returns the UID of the first task found with that name.

Comment: FYI: The de-duping (AddPrefixSuffix) is always run on the first instance of a task even after a second or third duplicate is found. That is why the `If InStr(...` line is there--to check first. This is simpler than other options such as storing whether or not the first task as been de-duplicated, or running through the list of tasks a second time.